# In PostgreSQL, how can I get the body of a prepared statement?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

My postgresql slow query log is showing lines like:

```
2014-07-11 21:00:34 GMT LOG:  duration: 539.036 ms  execute S_1: COMMIT
2014-07-11 21:00:39 GMT LOG:  duration: 608.964 ms  execute S_1: COMMIT
2014-07-11 21:00:39 GMT LOG:  duration: 604.911 ms  execute S_1: COMMIT
```

Is there a way for me to retrieve what prepared statement S_1 is so I can see which query is being slow?

Answer (score 0):

It's right there at the end of the log message. In this case, the prepared statement is a `COMMIT`.

This format applies to statements prepared via the [extended query protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-EXT-QUERY). If you're using an SQL [`PREPARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html), you'll find the original statement in a `DETAIL` message on the following line:

```
2014-07-11 21:00:39 GMT LOG:  duration: 0.118 ms  statement: EXECUTE q
2014-07-11 21:00:39 GMT DETAIL:  prepare: PREPARE q AS SELECT 1;
```